Match mainCamera and SceneView camera when hit play
I have a simple yet difficult task. When you hit play in Unity game camera should match camera in scene view. It should be done once not constantly.
This show zeros uniti I switch to sceneview in update
SceneView.lastActiveSceneView.camera.transform.position; 

This one null reference :
SceneView.currentDrawingSceneView.camera.transform.position; 

I tried to use [ExecuteAlways] to store position, but they get reset on play.

Use two flags and scene GUI callback:
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class SceneViewCameraSync : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool SceneViewGrab;
    private bool SceneViewInit;
    private Vector3 SceneViewPosition;
    private Quaternion SceneViewRotation;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!SceneViewGrab)
        {
            return;
        }

        SceneViewGrab = false;

        Camera.main.transform.position = SceneViewPosition;
        Camera.main.transform.rotation = SceneViewRotation;
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        SceneView.beforeSceneGui += OnBeforeSceneGui;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        SceneView.beforeSceneGui -= OnBeforeSceneGui;
    }

    private void OnBeforeSceneGui(SceneView obj)
    {
        if (SceneViewInit)
        {
            return;
        }

        SceneViewInit = true;

        SceneViewPosition = obj.camera.transform.position;
        SceneViewRotation = obj.camera.transform.rotation;

        SceneViewGrab = true;
    }
}

It will sync it once, after which you can move the game view camera as usual.
Consider using #if UNITY_EDITOR and that scene view may not be open or game view maximized.
